# How to query for entities with any item in a collection property matching a certain filter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Alright, so I'm using Entity Framework, code-first approach. I've got the following entity classes:

```
class EntityA
{
  public int EntityAId { get; set; }
  public virtaul ICollection<EntityB> Bs { get; set; }
}

class EntityB
{
  public int EntityBId { get; set; }
  public bool Foobar { get; set; }
  public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}
```

Given a `DbSet<EntityA>`, I'm trying to figure out how to query for all `EntityA`'s where any of the `EntityB`'s in `Bs` has `Foobar` equal to `true`.

How can I do this query, using EF fluent query API? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entities = dbSet.Where(m => m.Bs.Any(b => b.Foobar == true).ToList();
```

Should do it for you. Basically - give me all EntityAs that has any child EntityB where foobar equals true. For more information look into Linq and [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For your comment:

```
var dbSet= your dbset of EntityB
var id = the id of the EntityB you're querying with
var entities = dbSet.Where(m => m.A.Bs.Any(b => b.EntityBId == id)).Select(m => m.A).ToList();
```

So again, lets sound it out - give me every EntityA from a collection of EntityBs, where the EntityB's A navigation prop contains any EntityB with an id equal to a given id. Since you're querying a set of EntityBs, you'll have to select that entity's A. Geeze this is hard to say; too many as and bs.

Comment: What about an adjusted version of that query, that wants all `EntityA` that has any child `EntityB` from a given collection of `EntityB`?

Comment: @Ryan - I updated my answer. Just so you know, it would be a lot better to create a new question for each question you have. Always think about what will make it easier for future users to find answers to their questions.

Comment: You rock! I created a question specifically for the 2nd query, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702682/how-to-query-for-all-entitya-that-contain-any-entityb-within-a-collection-of-ent. Feel free to post your answer there and I'll check it off! Thanks.