# How to query for all EntityA that contain any EntityB within a collection of EntityBs?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given the following two example C# entity classes ...

```
class EntityA
{
  public int EntityAId { get; set; }
  public virtaul ICollection<EntityB> Bs { get; set; }
}

class EntityB
{
  public int EntityBId { get; set; }
  public string Foobar { get; set; }
  public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}
```

How would I go about using Entity Framework + LINQ to query for all `EntityA` that contain any `EntityB` within a provided collection of `EntityB`?

To clarify, if I have the following subset of `EntityB` ...

```
var bs = new List<EntityB>
{
  new EntityB { Foobar = "a" },
  new EntityB { Foobar = "b" },
  new EntityB { Foobar = "c" }
};
```

I want to find all `EntityA` where `EntityA.Bs` collection contains any of the possible `EntityB` within the above `bs` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you originally asked I thought you meant you only had a dbSet of EntityB. Now that I see you're trying to find any EntityA with an EntityB defined in a given set, we can simplify this:

```
var bs = your collection of EntityB
var dbSet = dbSet of type EntityA
var entities = dbSet.Where(m => m.Bs.Any(b =>
    bs.Any(b2 => b2.Foobar == b.Foobar).ToList();
```

So this will look through a collection of EntityA and will return any EntityA that has any EntityB with a Foobar equal to that of any in a given collection.

I would query from EntityA since you're getting a collection of EntityAs. But if you wanted to from EntityB you could do the following.

```
var entities = entityBSet.Where(m => 
    bs.Any(b => 
        b.Foobar == m.Foobar))
    .Select(m => m.A)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What about the collection of `EntityB`, though? I'm not dealing with a single `EntityB` that I'm looking for, I'm needing all `EntityA` that contain any `EntityB` from that small subset collection. Would it also be better to query using an `DbSet<EntityA>` instead of B?